A problem about morphisms from a genus 2 curve to a quartic curve.
I am to answer the following question.
Let $X$ be a projective non-singular curve of genus $2$, and let $K$ be an effective canonical divisor on it.
Pick any two points $P_1,P_2$ on $X$ with $K \not  \sim P_1 +P_2$.
Show that the divisor $K+P_1 +P_2$ induces a morphism to a quartic curve in $\mathbb P^2$.
Now by noting that $K$ has degree $2$, using Riemann-Roch tells us that $l(D) =3$ for $D$ the divisor in question, so we can certainly get a morphism to $\mathbb P^2$.
We can define the morphism by taking a basis $1,f_1,f_2$ of this space.
To show that the image lies in some quartic curve, we want some sort of relationship between the $f_i$.
It is however not obvious to me how to obtain one. I know that it would be enough to take some polynomial in them such that the poles cancel, but it is not clear how to do this.

The preimage of a line in $\mathbb{P}^2$ is a divisor from the linear system that gives the morphism; its degree is
$$
\deg(K + P_1 + P_2) = 4, 
$$
hence the image is a quartic curve (unless the morphism is a double covering over a conic in $\mathbb{P}^2$; this case you should exclude by using the assumption $P_1 + P_2 \not\sim K$).

I see why the degree of the morphism must be 4, however it is not clear to me how this relates to the structure of the image. Is there some result that describes this? I have a hunch that Riemann-Hurwitz can be applied, but I cannot see why we expect the image to be a smooth plane curve at all.

The image is a quartic curve (because the image of a proper morphism is an algebraic subvariety), but it is not smooth. In fact, a smooth quartic curve has genus 3, and there are no non-constant morphisms from a genus 2 curve to a genus 3 curve.
